# ADO - Problem passing variables in release tasks

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have 2 PS script in my 2 ADO tasks of RELEASE pipeline and I want to pass values from one to another. The problem is that it doesn't show correct value. As build pipeline works . I'm using CLASSIC EDITOR

Inline Powershell script #1

```
$a = "hello" 

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=test;isOutput=true;]$a"
```

Inline Powershell script #2

`Write-host $(test)`

How is this possible ? Any solution ?

Comment: Can you show the complete pipeline yaml file?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find examples here for the PowerShell: [Set a job-scoped variable from a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1)

Try to use script #1

```
$a = "hello" 

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=test]$a"
```

script #2

```
Write-host $env:TEST
Write-host $(test)
```

Additionally, check your variables here:

[image]